# which version of close() is called in my linux,from posix lib or kernel?

Tags: c++, c, linux, posix

When I `man -a close`, the first page is the POSIX man page, then I have a `close(2)`, (2 means system api or kernel func). This means there are at least 2 versions of `close()`.

For example, a code piece like this:

```
int fd = open("xxx");
........
close(fd);   -----here, which version is called,
                  is that one from the POSIX lib, or the raw system API?
```

P.S.: Hence my linux system includes a POSIX wrapper for most system API calls, how to discern whether my code is calling POSIX lib or original system API?

Answer (score 5):

POSIX is not a library, it's a standard. The POSIX version of a manual page tells you what the POSIX standard says the function should do (and what version of POSIX the page is based on). If you only rely on the behavior described in this page, your code should work on all systems that implement the POSIX standard (as long as they implement a current enough version).

The Linux version of the manpage tells you what the function actually does on your system. In the vast majority of cases the behavior described here will be a superset of the behavior described in the POSIX page, i.e. the Linux behavior will adhere to the POSIX standard, but it might also define cases that are undefined by POSIX or a function might accept additional options that aren't mandated by POSIX.

If you rely on any behavior not specified by POSIX, your code will likely only work on Linux systems.

Comment: tks，sepp2k.you are quite clear.POSIX is not a library, it's a standard-----------if there is some behavior originally not comform to POSIX in linux ,does linux make some wrap-up lib to meet it?if so any example?

Comment: POSIX requires `close` to be a cancellation point, and the Linux kernel knows nothing about thread cancellation, so the userspace libc wrapper for `close` must patch that up.

Comment: userspace libc wrapper for close _____ does libc wrapper wraps any system api for our application,e.g.,if we call close/open or other system api,wo actually call libc first ,then libc call kernel for usr? If this is the case,why should libc exist?

Answer (score 3):

"This means there are at least 2 version of close()."

No. It means there are 2 versions of the documentation for close.

Comment: as i know,there are several cases we need to explicitly declare whether we use POSIX or SYSTEMV style by some manner,(i.e.when use semaphore or thread,so on...),under these circumstance does it mean linux keep two implemnentation for some function? one comfrom to POSIX,but others conform to some old style?